# TextView same height as it's Text

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

How do we make the `TextView` to have the same height as it's text's height?

I have set the `layout_height` to `wrap_content` but there are still empty spaces on the top and the bottom of the text

Any idea?

Comment: paste your (TextView) xml code  here

Comment: you can set negative top-padding to textview

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you don't have any margins or paddings around the TextView. Also, setting the padding value to a negative one will solve the issue for you. You may need to play around with it for a while until you can get it right.